# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined - How do I solve this?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

Parse.com and JavaScript SDK.

I'm sure its simple, but I cannot seem to understand of fix the uncaught type error shown below. Why is this happening?

[image]

```
var Events = Parse.Object.extend("event");
var query = new Parse.Query(Events);
query.include("parent");

query.find({
    success: function(events) {
        for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
            var event = events[i];
            var zone = event.get("parent");
            console.log(zone.get("name"));              
        }
    },
    error: function(error) {
        alert(error);
    }
});
```

[image]

Comment: Error message is clear `zone` is undefined

Comment: Looks like the event doesn't have a parent.

Comment: but how to I solve it?

Comment: I assume those are credentials/keys inside the `Parse.initialize` call. You should revoke them.

Answer (score 1):

if i'm correct - include stop working. I have cloud code which worked two days ago and not working today. I used include in query, and it returns 'undefined' value today.

Comment: If include stopped working you would get a pointer instead of a full object, so you still wouldn't get `undefined` coming back.

Comment: @Timothy, I've removed include in query and got pointer (not undefined). When I called fetch on this pointer - got "Error: undefined undefined" (have no idea what does it mean).

Comment: Found problem. It was pointer to nonexistent record. Have no idea how does it happens.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the class "zone" did not have a "name" field" so console.log returned "undefined".